# Multi-direction scrolling FlatList (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I am facing an issue where I need to render a lot of grid elements on a component, starting out the grid will have 2,500 items(50 horizontally and 50 vertically) and this grid view needs to be scrollable in both directions and diagonally as well, I was able to do this by applying this prop `directionalLockEnabled={false}` to the regular react-native `ScrollView` but since I have a lot of items being rendered the `ScrollView` performance is suffering greatly, I wanted to replace this with a `FlatList` but couldn’t find a way to make it scrollable in all directions.

My question is if there is a way to make the `ScrollView` performant or to use `FlatList` and make it scrollable in all directions? or a better way to implement this?

Comment: As far as I know, the Flat list is the wrapper around the Scroll view, it uses Scroll view underneath, so there should the same property available.

Comment: I have looked at the docs, there no prop available for that

Comment: check the link, https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrollview-props I am not sure will it work for you or not

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Flashlist](https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list/) as it is very performant and work in all the directions

[Installation Guide](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/usage)

#### Usage

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { FlashList } from "@shopify/flash-list";

const DATA = [
  {
    title: "First Item",
  },
  {
    title: "Second Item",
  },
];

const MyList = () => {
  return (
    <FlashList
      data={DATA}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
      estimatedItemSize={200}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Is it able to scroll in both directions(diagonally) at the same time just like a scrollview? i dont see any props on the docs allowing for that

Comment: @Jhon can you add your code, i will convert that code into flashlist

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete answer

```
import React from 'react';
import {FlatList, ScrollView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
const App = () => {
  const data = [...Array(2500).keys()].map(i => i + 30);
  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={{flex: 1}}
      directionalLockEnabled={false}
      horizontal={true}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={50}
        data={data}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
            <View
              style={{
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                margin: 5,
                backgroundColor: '#0001',
              }}>
              <Text>I am {index}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: isn't it an anti-pattern to nest a Flatlist inside a ScrollView?

Comment: Plus is the performance still going to be affected because we are still using a regular ScrollView?

Comment: for performace imporovment use can use pagination and flatlist optimization. This is'nt best approach to load all of the  2500 item in flatlist at once. it will freez all of your Touches. you can try react-native-largelist for performance imporovment